# How to handle socket broken pipe [error 32] in php?

Tags: php, sockets

I have socket handler class, which is used to communicate to client with specific ip and port with the help of several socket functions. At the very first time when I am using `writetosocket()` function, it's working perfectly.

But when I am restarting client(with ip and port). And tries to use `writetosocket()` it returns me **broken pipe error with error code 32**. but after some successful execution of `socket_write` function. Means I am getting this error after some time duration, when I am writing data on socket. I read some solutions and tried most common solution where I am using `socket_shutdown` and `socket_close` to terminate socket connection properly whenever I am finding client is not responding. And after that I am again calling startconnection, which is giving me new socket. But still I am getting broken pipe error.

```
function startconnection(){
     /* Create a socket in the AF_INET family, using SOCK_STREAM for TCP connection */
     $this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
     if ($this->socket === false) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
            echo "$errorcode : $errormsg";
            return false;
     }
     else {
            echo "Socket successfully created.";
     }

     /* Accept incoming connections */
     $this->result = socket_connect($this->socket, $this->ipaddress, $this->port);
     if($this->result === false){
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
            echo "$errorcode : $errormsg";
            return false;
     }
     else {
            echo "successfully connected to $this->ipaddress, $this->port";
     }
     return true;
}


function writetosocket($input){
      $sent = socket_write($this->socket, $input, strlen($input));
      if($sent === false) {
            $errorcode = socket_last_error();
            $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
            echo "$errorcode : $errormsg";
            return false;
      }
      else {
            echo "Message Sent : $input";
      }
      return true;
}
```

Help me to understand and resolve this problem so that function can handle broken pipe error.

Comment: Show us more code (creation of `$this->socket` for example).

Comment: @nouney I have included code for creation of socket. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the **server socket** has closed and is no longer listening and the **client socket** is attempting to send data to the **server socket** after it has been closed but before the port is free to be used again (while it is in **TIME_WAIT**).

The **Server Socket** and the **Client Socket** both go through different steps before they become available for I/O:

### SERVER

1. socket()
2. bind()
3. listen()
4. accept()

### Client

1. socket()
2. bind() [optional, see below]
3. connect() [does an implicit bind on an ephemeral port if not already bound]

Comment: Thanks Charles, but I am actually connecting to client successfully, which I can verify with help of new resource id of socket. And after some successful socket write on client, I am getting broken pipe on socket write.